# Find the absolute maximum and absolute minimum values of f on the given interval.

Tags: calculus

$f(x) = x^2 e^{-x/2}, [-2,8]$

I have no idea as to how to solve this problem.  Can I please have an explanation as to finding the solution?

i edited the problem to look correct this time.

Comment: Do you know how to find relative (also known as local) extrema (maxima and minima)?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x) = x^2 e^{-x/2}$ or $f(x) = \frac{x^2 e^{-x}}{2}$?

Comment: the first one with -x/2 being the exponent of e

Answer (score 0):

At a local maximum or minimum $f^\prime(x_0) = 0$. You can determine the character of the stationary point by looking at how $f$ varies either side of $x_0$ or by calculating the value of $f^{\prime\prime}(x_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch the function. Locate any local extrema by finding where $f'(x)=0$, and identify whether they're maxima or minima using either your sketch or the sign of $f''(x)$. Finally, check the values at the ends of the interval to see if the maximum or minimum occurs there.

Comment: @jack Don't forget to look at the interval boundaries as well.